# setting a default in sfwidgetformchoice

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have an embedded form with a choice widget.  I'm trying to pass a default value from the main form to the widget.  I'm trying to pass the value to the form as an option, then once I have it in the embedded form do I just do something like:

```
new sfwidgetformchoice(array(...,'default' => $this->getOption('default'))
```

doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the form class:

`$this->setDefault('YOUR_WIDGET_NANE', $this->getOption('default'));`

Comment: Thanks, was still having problems, the choices array had integers as their key value, what ended up working was:

    $this->setDefault('widgetname', ''.$this->getOption('default')->getId())

Comment: if its not clear in that comment, the default value (an integer) needed to be changed into a string